# Copy and update nested object before setstate. react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have nested objects on my state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        aba1Array: [
            {
                item:[
                       {
                         id: 1,
                         nome: "apple",
                         selected:false,
                       },
                       {
                         id: 2,
                         nome: "juice",
                         selected:false,
                       }
                     ]
             },
             {
                item:[
                       {
                        id: 3,
                        nome: "apple",
                        selected:false,
                       },
                       {
                        id: 4,
                        nome: "juice",
                        selected:false,
                       }
                     ]
              }
              ],
             };
}
```

Now I want to make a copy of the array, update an item, and setState again (is this the correct way to update, right ?), how to do this ? this is my current code:

```
updateItem(id){
    let newItems = Object.keys(this.state.aba1Array).map((subitem) => {
    subitem.item.map((item) => item.id===id ? {...item, selected: true } : item);
    });
    this.setState({ aba1Array: newItems });
}
```

this is returning:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'subitem.item.map')

edited: The problem begun when I added second level of nesting , before it was working fine with just one level , like this :

```
let newItems = Object.keys(this.state.aba1Array).map((item) => {
         item.id===id ? {...item, selected: true } : item);
```

edited2:  in another part of the screen where I only list the items , i'm using:

`listItem() { 
    return this.state.aba1Array.map((subitem)=> { 
     return ( subitem.item.map((item) => { return ( <View>`
...

and it works fine. Why in the update function it gives me error ? I don't understand

Edited3: - SOLUTION -

My solution was to use library object-path-immutable:

```
updateItem(itemIndex,subIndex){
        const newObj = immutable.update(this.state.aba1Array, [subIndex,'item', itemIndex , 'selected' ], v => true );
        this.setState({ aba1Array: newObj });
    }
```

Comment: Object.assign() is usually method for copying objects

Comment: It is, but if its a deeply nested object, it might not be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution :
I forgot to return the value on map function , so the new array wasnt getting the full tree of the object , the best solution is:

```
 let newItems = this.state.aba1Array.map((subitem) => {
            subitem.item.map((item) => {
                item.selected = true;
                return item;
            })
            return subitem;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use library object-path-immutable:

```
updateItem(itemIndex,subIndex){
        const newObj = immutable.update(this.state.aba1Array, [subIndex,'item', itemIndex , 'selected' ], v => true );
        this.setState({ aba1Array: newObj });
    }
```